# cookie->getValue() results in a FatalErrorException

Tags: symfony, cookies

I set the cookie in javascript during a previous session. I can see that the cookie exists via Firebug. However when I try to get the cookie value in my controller code I get the Fatal error.

Code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

        $cookies = $request->cookies;

        $cookieState = ($cookies->has('state') ? $cookies->get('state') : 0);
        $cookieLocationId = $cookies->has('locationId') ? $cookies->get('locationId') : 0;

        if (!$cookieState && !$cookieLocationId)
        {
            return array();
        }
        else
        {
            if($cookieLocationId)
            {
                $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('workoutexchange_wxexchange_default_location', array('locationId' => $cookieLocationId->getValue())));
            }

            $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('workoutexchange_wxexchange_default_state', array('state' => $cookieState->getValue())));
        }
}
```

Resultant error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/workoutexchange/src/WorkoutExchange/WXExchangeBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 38
```

Maybe I'm not retrieving the cookies properly or something?

Please help me read the cookies properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite your code as :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $cookieState = $request->cookies->get('state', 0);
    $cookieLocationId = $request->cookies->get('locationId', 0);

    if (!$cookieState && !$cookieLocationId)
    {
        return array();
    }
    else
    {
        if($cookieLocationId)
        {
            $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('workoutexchange_wxexchange_default_location', array('locationId' => $cookieLocationId->getValue())));
        }

        $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('workoutexchange_wxexchange_default_state', array('state' => $cookieState->getValue())));
    }
}
```

It would be much cleaner, and should solve your problem

And don't forgot to import the class:

> use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

`var_dump()` to the rescue... I figured out that the `$cookies->get('state')` was returning the actual value and not the cookie object.